# Использование Яндекс.Карт в некоммерческих целях

Tags: авторские-права

Доброго времени суток!

Возможно, я обращаюсь не совсем по адресу, но я надеюсь, что вы сможете помочь мне с ответом.

Я являюсь студентом и обучаюсь на первом курсе. Для осуществления учебного проекта я и моя команда хотели бы использовать ваш сервис. Я прочла пользовательское соглашение, но не нашла там ответа на интересующий меня вопрос: можно ли использовать ИЗОБРАЖЕНИЕ (например, скриншот) карты данного города, но не сам сервис (!) в некоммерческих целях?

Если да, то разрешено ли это самое изображение подвергать обработке, например в программе PhotoShop и т.д? То есть, изменять цвета, стирать некоторые объекты с карты и т.п?

Спасибо за внимание!

Comment: StackOveflow не имеет никакого отношения к Яндексу.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что вопрос нужно адресовать в техподдержку Яндекс.Карт. Stackoverflow не имеет отношения к Яндекс.